# Is it safe to assume that a JWT is valid if the library says so?

Tags: rsa, jwt

This is my first time using JWT. I'm using the jwcrypto library as directed, and the key I'm using is an RSA key I generated with OpenSSL.

My initial inclination was to store the JWT in the database with the user's row, and then validate the token's claims against the database on every request.

But then it occurred to me that the token payload is signed with my server's private key.

Assuming my private key is never compromised, is it safe to assume that all data contained in the JWT, presented as a Bearer token by the user, is tamper-proof? I understand that it is potentially readable by third parties, since I'm not encrypting.

What I want to know is, is there anything I need to do to validate the user's JWT besides decrypt it and let the library tell me if there's anything wrong?

Comment: do you mean secret key or private key?

Comment: Please correct your question or your title. One says you're not encrypting, but the other talks about decryption. If you just mean signing and verifying, use those terms instead.

Comment: @OnNIX May I suggest a new title? *"Is it safe to assume that a JWT is valid if the library says so?"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to verify a JWT is to check it's algorithm, signature, expiry and issuer. Other claims can be checked too.

**Signature**

For RS256, the auth server will calculate a SHA256 hash of the header and payload, and sign it with it's private key. To verify the signature, the relying party again calculates the hash of the header and payload, and checks that it matches the signature decrypted with the public key.

Since the header and payload aren't encrypted, they can be tampered with, but then it won't match the signature.

**Algorithm**

Two serious vulnerabilities are possible when the server does not check the `"alg"` field [[1]](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries). This is because some JWT libraries verify the signature automatically using the algorithm provided in the header.

Firstly, if a hacker sends a JWT with the `alg` equal to `none`, the signature won't be checked.

Secondly, some faulty library implementations store the symmetric secret key and asymmetric public key in the same variable. If you've stored an RSA public key expecting an asymmetric algorithm, and a hacker sends a JWT with a symmetric signing algorithm, your server will check if the JWT was signed with the *public* key. Since the hacker has access to the public key, they can easily create valid JWT signatures.

**Payload Claims**

JWT libraries will check the current time is between the issued time `iat` and expiry time `exp`. Instead of checking the `exp`, some people prefer to check the current time is less than the issued time plus the maximum acceptable JWT lifetime.

The issuer `iss` should match the expected issuer.

**Sources**

[1]: https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries
[2]: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/validate-jwts